# How can I configure the sencha app build command to use a custom named app folder?

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

I need to use a custom named 'app' folder for my Ext JS 4.1.3 application. Sencha documentation is clear that this folder name is a configurable value called 'appFolder'.

Environment:
Ext JS 4.1.3
Sencha Cmd 3.1.2.342 
Ruby 1.9

Steps that I took:

```
sencha generate workspace C:\temp\workspace 
sencha -sdk C:\tools\extjs4.1.3 generate app common C:\temp\workspace\common 
cd C:\temp\workspace\common 
sencha app build 

SUCCESSFUL
```

edited the app.js and set appFolder: 'custom':

```
Ext.application({ 
    appFolder: 'custom' ...
```

Also renamed the 'C:\temp\workspace\common\app' folder to 'C:\temp\workspace\common\custom'

```
sencha app build.

[ERR] def was null 
[ERR] failed to find meta class definition for name common.controller.Main 
[ERR] def was null 
[ERR] failed to find meta class definition for name common.view.Viewport 
[ERR] C2008: Requirement had no matching files (common.view.Viewport) -- unknown 
-file:-1 
[ERR] Error executing page compilation Failed to find any files for C:\TEMP\workspace\common\app.js::ApplicationAutoDependency::common.view.Viewport 
[ERR] 
[ERR] BUILD FAILED 
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExBuild: com.sencha.exceptions.ExBuild: Failed to find any files for C:\TEMP\workspace\common\app.js::ApplicationAutoDependency::common.view.Viewport 
[ERR] 
[ERR] Total time: 6 seconds 
[ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line: 
C:\TEMP\workspace\common\.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:408: The following error occurred while executing this line: 
C:\TEMP\workspace\common\.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:381: com.sencha.exceptions.ExBuild: com.sencha.exceptions.ExBuild: Failed to find any files for C:\TEMP\workspace\common\app.js::ApplicationAutoDependency::common.view.Viewport
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit file `yourAppFolder/.sencha/app/sencha.cfg`

Change `classpath=${app.dir}/app` to `classpath=${app.dir}/custom`